# C++11 constructor delegation with aggregate initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, aggregate-initialization, delegating-constructor

Is it possible to invoke aggregate initialization within my own definition of the default ctor?

GCC complains "error: constructor delegates to itself" with the below code:

```
struct X {
  int x, y, z, p, q, r;
  X(): x{}, y{}, z{}, p{}, q{}, r{} { }  // cumbersome
//X(): X{} { }  // the idea is nice but doesn't compile
};
```

I'm using `memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this))` in the ctor body at the moment.

Comment: If `X` doesn't have to be an aggregate itself, you could move `x, y, z...` to a base class, and aggregate-initialize that base class on a member initialization list

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Interesting idea though my colleagues will frown upon it if I do it in a production code.

Comment: memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this)) is hurting my inner peace ...

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to fool overload resolution in the following way:

```
struct X {
  int x, y, z, p, q, r;
  X(int) : x{}, y{}, z{}, p{}, q{}, r{} { }
  X() : X(0) { }
};
```

Another way would be to use in-class default member initialization:

```
struct X {
  int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, p = 0, q = 0, r = 0;
};
```

In your specific example you could also do:

```
struct X {
  std::array<int, 6> vars{};
};
```

Comment: I think OP meant to remove the `x{}, y{}, z{}, p{}, q{}, r{}` part altogether

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki the OP says that he/she is using now `memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this))`

Comment: No, OP basically asked how to replicate Java's this() condtructor call in C++

Comment: @101010 yea, so he wants to initialize part of memory where struct is allocated ( variables inside struct ) with one function. 
So You both got right.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the CRTP to do this.

```
template<class C>
struct ZeroInitialized
{
    ZeroInitialized() { memset((C*)this, 0, sizeof(C)); }
};


struct A : ZeroInitialized<A>
{
    int x, y, z, p, q, r;
};
```

But I'm making no guarantees this is safe.

Comment: that's not what I meant :( . By aggregate-initialization I meant `struct A : B { A() : B{} {} };` with `struct B { int x, y, z; };`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, you meant to shove the members to the base, but it doesn't solve the OP's problems, only renames the class where it appears. I merged the two approaches.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, fine no mention of you is made on this abomination :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29) - move the body of your constructor to separate class:

```
struct X {
  int x, y, z, p, q, r;
};

struct XFactory {
  X create();
};

X XFactory::create()
{
   X x{};
   // do needed modification
   return x;
}
```

---

Although I'd always prefer factory pattern - there is also other way more aligned to your explicit needs - define default constructor for each of your member data:

```
template <typename T>
struct DefaultConstructibleData
{
   T data;
   DefaultConstructibleData() data{} {} 
};
```

And use it:

```
struct X {
  DefaultConstructibleData<int> x, y, z, p, q, r;
  X() 
  {         
       // do whatever you needs to do
       // all x,y,... are already constructed to their defaults
  }
};
```

Comment: Redundant copying galore. And it doesn't remove any of the cumbersome code the OP complained about, just moves it outside of the c'tor.

Comment: @StoryTeller RVO - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization - prevents from redundant copying...

Comment: RVO is an optimization (not a guarantee), and there must still be at least on copy made if you do assignments. Not to mention, you make it impossible to create const objects.

Comment: I stand corrected on the const objects front. Had a moment of confusion. But your copies are not all optimized out. Semantically the compiler can't do that. That's why move c'tor were invented in the first place.

Comment: @StoryTeller Even if RVO is not working here (it won't for copmplicated classes) then this x here is eXpiring Value here - so move constructor will be invoked here automatically - no copying... unless moving not defined. Of course for struct filled with int's - RVO is practically always working...